# Is there any way to login with AzureAD in electron js?

Tags: electron, msal.js

I want to integrate AzureAD flow with the below-given repo.
https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet-electron

Answer (score 2):

The [msal-electron-poc](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/msal-electron-poc/lib/msal-electron-proof-of-concept) is a proof of concept implementation of msal specifically for Electron and it shows how to acquire tokens using the Auth Code Grant in an Electron environment. The user will have to implement features as silent token acquisition and caching.

The closest thing we have to an electron sample is the msal-electron-poc library and the msal-electron-sample-app in the microsoft-authentication-library-for-js GitHub repo. We currently don't have any library that supports Electron out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I have tried the above solution but it's not working.so is there any other way to integrate AzureAD without using msal-electron-poc?
and it is working with full repo https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js.

Comment: Hi @Raj, Currently there are no other official alternatives today, but we can expect in the future.